# Display the value of a Sub property of a Member in a Collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, telerik-grid

I'm binding a ObservableCollection to a Grid, the class T that I am using would have an structure similar to this:

```
public class MyObject {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Address MyAddress {get;set;}
}

public class Address {
    public String Street {get;set}
}
```

So I am binding an ObservableCollection to a Telerik RadGridView and, what I want to do, is to display the property Address.Street for each of the elements in the collection but I cannot just figure out how.

I tried to do bindings like the following:

```
{Binding MyAddress.Street}
{Binding MyAddress/Street}
{Binding Address.Street}
```

but non of those work. Is there a way to set the Path property of the binding to do such thing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `GridViewDataColumn` with `DataMemberBinding`, then you might have to use a cell template to render the sub-member properties (I would have thought `DataMemberBinding="{Binding Address.Street}"` should work, but if it doesn't, well ...):

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Address}">
    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Street}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```